# What is a net flow?

Tags: network-flow

I tried to find strict definition in Google and books, but didn't succeed. How it connected with max flow and residual network?

Comment: In what context did you see it?

Comment: @nirshahar net flow across the cut

Comment: Across *what* cut? are you talking about a max-flow network problem?

Comment: @nirshahar yes, as I mentioned

Comment: If the flow is from $s$ to $t$ and cut is $(A,B)$ with $s \in A$ and $t \in B$, net flow is probably referring to the amount of flow on the edges in $A \times B$ minus the amount of flow on the edges in $B \times A$.

Comment: @Steven Perhaps you could write this as an answer? It seems to answer this question.